# Checking if a LI contains a <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am stumped not sure why feel like I am close but any help would be appreciated.

I am make the system check and see if a li.anyclass has a child   and if it does stop if not then i want to it to show something else.

```js
if ("li.aaProfileAttrFile").has("img")) {
  alert('Class exists');
} else {
  alert('Class does not exist');
}
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery.  Look at your code.

Comment: Like I said I am trying to piece this together not sure if I should be using jquery or Javascript.  Everything I have tried has not worked.  I have also tried this and it doesn't work.const div = document.querySelector('.aaProfileAttrFile');
if(div.classList.contains('img')){
     alert("IT DOES");
     } else {
     alert("it does not");
     }

Comment: Where is the jQuery?  Where is the jQuery operator in your code?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks I already looked there. I am not expert obviously or I would have figured it out already.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/  `$( ".myClass" );` <= there are tons of examples showing that to use jQuery you use the `$` variable, giving it a selector.  Your example question is not following this pattern.

Comment: Use each() and find() instead of has().

Comment: Unclear if you wish to target an `<img>` element or a `.img` class... Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on `jquery`. I used the `each()` method, with which you check all `li` tags for the presence of an `img` tag inside.

```js
$('li.aaProfileAttrFile').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).find('img').length) {
    console.log('Class exists ' + index);
  } else {
    console.log('Class does not exist ' + index);  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="aaProfileAttrFile"><img href=""></li>
  <li class="aaProfileAttrFile"></li>
  <li class="aaProfileAttrFile"><img href=""></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: thank you this seems to be doing what I wanted

Comment: @KirkSturgulewski, If my answer helped you, then mark my answer as resolved by checking the checkbox to the left of my answer.